# How to find employee by ID in LINQ

Tags: linq

How to find employee by ID and group two Max and Min Time in where id=1 and Date="2017-05-01"  Same Row using LINQ.

```
 List<bllcls> obj = new List<bllcls>();
        obj.Add(new bllcls { id =1 , Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01"),Time="08:00:00" });
        obj.Add(new bllcls { id =1 , Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01"),Time="19:00:00"  });
        obj.Add(new bllcls { id =2 , Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01"),Time="08:00:00" });
        obj.Add(new bllcls { id =2 , Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01"),Time="19:00:00"  });
```

from (id=1)

how to?

i need in this format

```
Row 1 = ID , DATE ,      MIN TIME  , MAX TIME
col   = 1  , 2017-05-01, 08:00:00  , 19:00:00

Row 2 = ID , DATE ,      MIN TIME  , MAX TIME
col   = 2  ,2017-05-01, 08:00:00  , 19:00:00
```

Comment: Show what you tried so far and where you are having problems

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` is your friend:

```
var query = obj.GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(grp => new { Id = grp.Key, MinDate = grp.Min(x => x.Date), MaxDate = grp.Max(x => x.Date) });
```

If you want it only for a specified `Id` use `Where`:

```
var id1Query = query.Where(x => x.Id == 1);
```

If you only expect one use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`:

```
var id1 = query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, And tell me that how to retun in List

  obj=obj.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(grp => new { Id = grp.Key, MinDate = grp.Min(x => x.Date), MaxDate = grp.Max(x => x.Date) }).ToList();

Comment: @hamza: you want a new `List<bllcls>`?

Comment: yes i want to save into new list List<bllcls> obj1;

Comment: @hamza: but your class `bllcls` has only one `DateTime` property not two. Where you want to store the min- and max-date?

Comment: okay so how can i save date into string or datetime variable?

Comment: @hamza: above i have shown you how to store it in an anonymous type, append `ToList` if you want a list. If you want `DateTime` you have to tell me how you want to store two datetimes in one. If you want a string you have to tell me in what format.

Comment: i updated my question if you know so tell me.

Answer (score 0):

try Code

```
 Var result= ( from p in obj  
               select new
                {
                   Id=p.id,
                   Mindate=obj.where(c=>c.id==p.id).Min(c.date),
                   Maxdate= obj.where(c=>c.id==p.id).Max(c.date),
                 }).Distinct().ToList();
```